# Telerik ASP.Net Radgrid show / hide filters

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I am building an ASP.Net Telerik Radgrid at runtime based on a passed in configuration so there is no radgrid tag on my ASPX page. I am trying to implement functionality where I can add a button to the header of the grid that will show or hide the column filters.

I am using a [Command Item Template](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-commanditemtemplate.html) to provide the show/hide button which is appearing but when I click the button to show or hide the filters with the `ShowHideFilters` Javascript method using the [grid.get_masterTableView()](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-get-mastertableview.html) function it can not find the `get_masterTableView()` method on the grid object.

Any idea why this method is missing or a better alternative to achieve the behavior I require?

[Telerik Radgrid Client API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-get-mastertableview.html)

**JavaScript example from Telerik API**

```
function getMasterTableView() {
    var grid = $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
    var masterTableView = grid.get_masterTableView();              
}
```

**Page**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ShowGrid.aspx.vb" Inherits="ShowGrid" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="ShowGrid" runat="server">

        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>

        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
            <AjaxSettings>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ConfigureGrid">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ConfigureGrid" LoadingPanelID="AjaxLoadingPanel" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

        <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="AjaxLoadingPanel" runat="server"/>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="PrimaryDataSource" runat="server"/>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function ShowHideFilters()
        {
            var grid = document.getElementById("ConfigureGrid")
            if (grid)
            {
                var masterTableView = grid.get_masterTableView();
                window.alert(masterTableView.id)
            }

            window.alert(grid.id)
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Code behind**

Build the grid from the ground up in the Page_Init

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    Try
        BuildConfiguration()
        CreateTitleObject()
        CreateRadFilter()
        LoadDataSource()
        CreateRadGrid()
    Catch ex As Exception
        CreateExceptionDisplay(ex)
    End Try

End Sub
```

**Item template**

```
Friend Class RadGridCommandItemFilterTemplate
    Implements ITemplate

    Protected showHideFilterButton As Button

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub InstantiateIn(ByVal container As Control) Implements ITemplate.InstantiateIn
        showHideFilterButton = New Button
        showHideFilterButton.EnableTheming = True
        showHideFilterButton.ID = "showHideFilterButton"
        showHideFilterButton.Text = "Show / Hide Filters"
        showHideFilterButton.CommandName = "ShowHideFilters"
        showHideFilterButton.OnClientClick = "ShowHideFilters()"
        container.Controls.Add(showHideFilterButton)
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Adding the item template**

```
grid.MasterTableView.CommandItemTemplate = New RadGridCommandItemFilterTemplate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Telerik support I have come up with this.

**Item template**

```
Friend Class RadGridCommandItemFilterTemplate
    Implements ITemplate

    Public showHideFilter As ImageButton
    Public bannerTitle As Label

    Private gridClientID As String
    Private showFilter As Boolean = False
    Private title As String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(gridClientID As String, showfilter As Boolean, title As String)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.gridClientID = gridClientID
        Me.showFilter = showfilter
        Me.title = title
    End Sub

    Public Sub InstantiateIn(ByVal container As Control) Implements ITemplate.InstantiateIn

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title) Then
            bannerTitle = New Label With {.Text = title, .CssClass = "title"}
            container.Controls.Add(bannerTitle)
        End If

        If showFilter Then
            showHideFilter = New ImageButton With {.ID = "showHideFilter",
                                                 .CommandName = "ShowHideFilters",
                                                 .CssClass = "searchButton"}

            showHideFilter.Attributes.Add("onclick", (Convert.ToString("setFilter('") & gridClientID) + "'); return false;")

            container.Controls.Add(showHideFilter)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

**Java script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        setFilter('ConfigureGrid');
    }

    function setFilter(gridClientID) {
        var grid = $find(gridClientID);
        if (grid.get_masterTableView().get_isFilterItemVisible()) {
            grid.get_masterTableView().hideFilterItem();
        }
        else {
            grid.get_masterTableView().showFilterItem()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have proper grid id and if you use $find method. Code provided is a little messy and I'm not sure which part is invoked.

In function getMasterTableView you use $find but you have wrong id I guess. Also if this function is in javascript file then "<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>" won't be resolved to correct id. It must be in aspx file to do so.

In function ShowHideFilters you use wrong function getElementById will return DOM object not Telerik one. Please also note that your grid has "TestGrid" id.

UPDATE:
To get master table you need to use find method. If you want more generic solution then I reccomend to add simple css class to your button. And then in onLoad event add handlers to those buttons. If you have jQuery element that is placed inside grid then you can use following function to locate grid dynamically:

```
function getParentGrid($element) {
    var $parentGrid = $element.closest("div.RadGrid");
    var parentGridId = $parentGrid[0].id;
    return  window.$find(parentGridId);
}
```

Comment: I can't use the $find method as the component is created at runtime from the code behind. There is no <telerik:RadGrid tag. The TestGrid was a test and I will remove it from the question.

Comment: I have updated answer maybe that code snippet will be helpfull for you

Comment: ANyway, make sure to set an ID of your grid, controls created programatically need those IDs so they can load their ViewState after a postback. Do not leave their generation to chance and to the framework.

Also, add a "return false;" statement in the button client-side handler if you do not want it to postback (I do not see code that handles it, so I assume it is not needed and you want this done on the client).